# Help with 'Update Records' element after a flow with loop

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, recordtriggeredflow

I'm relatively new to flows and super new to loops. I've watched several flow tutorials and they all seem to follow the pattern of: a record is triggered > loop through related records > assign values to those looped through records > update the related records from the loop. I'm trying to trigger a flow > loop through related records and get information > update record that triggered the flow.

Scenario is, Subscription object has related Billing records and related Contact Roles. When a billing record is created, loop through contact roles where subscription Id matches, get all the email addresses of the contacts, and stamp them into a field on the Billing record.

The Assign Values assignment uses the Billing record field as the variable with an Add operator and the value is a formula ({!Loop_through_Contact_Roles.Contact.Email} & ",")  It looks to be working when I debug, up until the Update Billing records element. Does it look like I'm missing any steps? For the Update Records element, should I select use the record that triggered the flow?

[image]

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.`For the Update Records element, should I select use the record that triggered the flow?` - YES. Note that you'll end up with a trailing comma `(,)` in the concatenation of emails field. You should use [edit] to expose the issue with the Update Records element

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! If I am understanding exactly what you are doing, I set up something similar in a Playground Org using Account instead of Billing, and Contact instead of Contact Role. I had 2 related Contacts with email addresses, and I ended up with two email addresses in my new Account field. So that worked for me. As *copredy* said, please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. You are correct, cropredy, I ended up with a comma in my field. I was able to resolve the issue by assigning my formula to a variable (I had it assigning to the field) and then using that variable in my Update Records step.